# Can VEX prefixes be used with general-purpose instructions?

Tags: x86, machine-code

I'm finding both the Intel and AMD manuals unclear on whether the `VEX` prefix can be used on instructions that do not define special behavior for it, the way it appears `REX` can. For example, `CPUID` is `0F A2`, can I encode it as `VEX.LIG.0F.WIG A2` (`C4 E1 78 A2`)? What about `NOP` using the 2-byte `VEX` form of `VEX.LIG.WIG 90` (`C5 F8 90`)?

If this is allowed, must the unused fields be set to specific values? What about `EVEX`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Intel's insn ref manual (volume 2) is perfectly clear.  See the link in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) wiki.  It lists all valid encodings for every instruction mnemonic.  It separately lists the non-VEX and VEX encoding for `PSHUFB`, for example.  Similarly, the Intel Future Extensions pdf lists all the valid encodings for every EVEX instruction.

It *only* lists a non-VEX encoding for `imul`, because there is no VEX encoding.

It *only* lists a VEX encoding for `pext r64a, r64b, r/m64`, because that BMI2 integer instruction is only available with a VEX encoding.

Comment: Volume 3 barely even mentions VEX (unless you mean AMD's?). Do you have a perfectly clear quote? All I see is ambiguous, like "The use of VEX prefix in an Intel 64 instruction is optional". Maybe they just don't list `VEX-NOP` because there's no point?

Comment: @Trillian: My bad, I meant vol2, the insn ref manual.  The one with an entry for each insn separately, that lists all valid encodings.  I've never actually tried using a VEX instead of a REX prefix for instructions like `and`, but I assume it just faults on an illegal instruction.  I think if VEX was ever useful to save code bytes (for non-vector instructions that use some of the same prefixes), the encoding would be listed.